# How to delete a node label by command and api?

Tags: kubernetes

Add label to nodes:

```
$ kubectl label nodes 10.xx.xx.xx key1=val1
```

If I want to delete `label(key1=val1)` on node(10.xx.xx.xx), how can I delete by kubectl command and API?

Answer (score 197):

***create labels for the nodes:***

`kubectl label node <nodename> <labelname>=allow`

***delete above labels from its respecitve nodes:***

`kubectl label node <nodename> <labelname>-`

Comment: To remove for all nodes "kubectl label  --all <labelname>-"

Comment: For more than one node "kubectl label  <node1> <node2> <labelname>-"

Comment: @Hem nice, but shouldn't it be "kubectl label nodes --all <labelname>-"? For me that did work at least.

Comment: @NicolasMommaerts, well, if you'd like to do it for all nodes, not a subset.

Comment: @Hem, no I meant it seems you forgot the word 'nodes' in both your examples. You need to specify you want to label a node (or some other type of resource).

Comment: @NicolasMommaerts, yeah I you're right. Unfortunately, SO does not allow me to edit.

Answer (score 34):

Below command worked for me to remove label:

```
kubectl label node <nodename> <label>-
```

Note:  The syntax is a minus sign directly after the key. For example, if the node name is worker1 and the label is system=workernode, you can remove a label with the following command.

```
kubectl label node worker1 system-
```

Answer (score 21):

From kubectl label -h:

> Update pod 'foo' by removing a label named 'bar' if it exists.
>      Does not require the --overwrite flag.
>      $ kubectl label pods foo bar-

The same works for nodes.

Answer (score 19):

To add a label to kubernetes nodes:

```
kubectl label node "your-node-name" node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker
```

To remove a label from kubernetes nodes:

```
kubectl label node "your node-name" node-role.kubernetes.io/worker-
```

**Note:** To remove a label put a "-" symbol at the end of your label name

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me.
Add Label

```
kubectl label node <node name> node-role.kubernetes.io/<role name>=<key - (any name)>
```

Remove label

```
kubectl label node <node name> node-role.kubernetes.io/<role name>-
```

[For More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854905/how-to-add-roles-to-nodes-in-kubernetes/59462802#59462802)

Answer (score 9):

To remove the label you can use

kubectl label nodes 10.xx.xx.xx key1-

Answer (score 3):

You can remove label this way

```
kubectl label nodes <node_name> key1- key2-

eg: kubectl label nodes ip-172-20-22-247 key1- key2-
```

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, correct kubectl example to delete label, but there is no mention of removing labels using API clients. if you want to remove label using the API, then you need to provide a new body with the `labelname: None` and then patch that body to the node or pod. I am using the kubernetes python client API for example purpose

```
from pprint import pprint
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()
client.configuration.debug = True

api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()

body = {
    "metadata": {
        "labels": {
            "label-name": None}
        }
}

api_response = api_instance.patch_node("minikube", body)

print(api_response)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the label from a single node using the following kubectl command

`kubectl label node 10.xx.xx.xx Key1-`

If you want to remove the label for all the nodes, use the following command

`kubectl label nodes --all Key1-`

Comment: I like this one, it help me to remove all the labels at once

Answer (score 1):

just try that and it should be

```
kubectl label nodes work1 node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=
```

to verify and compare with other nodes

```
kubectl get nodes
kubectl get nodes --show-labels
```

Comment: When I did this it responded with a comforting and affirming `namespace/X unlabeled`.

Comment: it seems the sessions in this site works in some weird way, my response belongs to another thread I had open too, for marking node as worker

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to see existing labels for the nodes 
   kubectl get nodes --show-labels
2. Then, list the key_name and node_name you want to modify
3. Then, kubectl label node node_name key_name-

Answer (score 0):

To add label to your node

```
kubectl label node ip-172-31-15-136 mynode=tst mnode=ssd
```

To remove label from your node

```
kubectl label node ip-172-31-15-136 mynode- mynode-
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove or re-name use parameter `--overwrite` e.g

```
kubectl label nodes node-name --overwrite label-name
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove a label from all nodes:

```
kubectl label node --all label-
```

Notice the `-` concatenated to the label without any space.