# How to add roles to nodes in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

When I provision a Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm, I get my nodes tagged as "none". It's a known bug in Kubernetes and currently a PR is in progress.

However, I would like to know if there is an option to add a Role name manually for the node.

```
root@ip-172-31-14-133:~# kubectl get nodes
NAME               STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
ip-172-31-14-133   Ready     master    19m       v1.9.3
ip-172-31-6-147    Ready     <none>    16m       v1.9.3
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

This worked for me:

`kubectl label node cb2.4xyz.couchbase.com node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker`

```
NAME                                          STATUS    ROLES           AGE       VERSION
cb2.4xyz.couchbase.com                          Ready     custom,worker   35m       v1.11.1
cb3.5xyz.couchbase.com                          Ready     worker          29m       v1.11.1
```

I could not delete/update the old label, but I can live with it.

Comment: You can delete "custom" role with command  kubectl label node cb2.4xyz.couchbase.com node-role.kubernetes.io/custom-

Comment: same answer <> better answer :)

Comment: Is there a an actual reason why you need to add `worker=worker` and not simply `node-role.kubernetes.io=worker`? Is there a convention people should abide by?

Comment: Oh, I see. My version doesn't change the ROLES column actually :)
But this works though and it seems simpler and more elegant:
`kubectl label node cb2.4xyz.couchbase.com node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=""`

Comment: This command removed the `master` role from my three k8s nodes:
`kubectl label node k8s1 k8s2 k8s3 node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`
Hope this helps. (k8s=1.21.13)

Answer (score 63):

A node role is just a label with the format `node-role.kubernetes.io/<role>`

You can add this yourself with `kubectl label`

Comment: Exact command would look like this: kubectl label node aNodeName node-role.kubernetes.io/custom=

Comment: just to add that `kubernetes.io/role=<role_here>` works as well

Comment: You shouldn't use `kubernetes.io/role` anymore. https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-auth/0000-20170814-bounding-self-labeling-kubelets.md#proposal

Comment: Yeah this no longer is supported to set via kubelet args from Kubernetes version 1.16. Does anyone know a way to set it at the time of launching the workers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also looking for the best way to do this post k8s version 1.16. Any progress here?

Answer (score 32):

**Default**
[image]

**Add Role**

```
kubectl label node <node name> node-role.kubernetes.io/<role name>=<key - (any name)>
```

[image]

**Remove Role**

```
kubectl label node <node name> node-role.kubernetes.io/<role name>-
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

**Before label:**

```
general@master-node:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME          STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
master-node   Ready    master   23m   v1.18.2
slave-node    Ready    <none>   19m   v1.18.2
```

> `kubectl label nodes <your_node> kubernetes.io/role=<your_label>`
>
> In my case **slave-node** e.g.
>
> `kubectl label nodes slave-node kubernetes.io/role=worker`

**After label:**

```
general@master-node:~$ kubectl label nodes slave-node kubernetes.io/role=worker
node/slave-node labeled
general@master-node:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME          STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
master-node   Ready    master   24m   v1.18.2
slave-node    Ready    worker   21m   v1.18.2
```

**You can also change the label.**  Just put `--overwrite`

> `kubectl label --overwrite nodes <your_node> kubernetes.io/role=<your_new_label>`
>
> e.g.
>
> `kubectl label --overwrite nodes slave-node kubernetes.io/role=worker1`

**After overwriting the label:**

```
general@master-node:~$ kubectl label --overwrite nodes slave-node kubernetes.io/role=worker1
node/slave-node labeled
general@master-node:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME          STATUS   ROLES     AGE   VERSION
master-node   Ready    master    36m   v1.18.2
slave-node    Ready    worker1   32m   v1.18.2
```

Comment: repeatedly running is only appending the role not updating it.

Answer (score 5):

**Add Roles**

```
$ kubectl get nodes 

master  Ready    control-plane,master   166m    v1.21.1
worker1  Ready    worker                 48m     v1.21.1
worker2  Ready    worker                 16m     v1.21.1
worker3   Ready    worker                 9m57s   v1.21.1    

$ kubectl label node worker1  node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker

$ kubectl label node worker2  node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker

$ kubectl label node worker3  node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker
```

In case if you wanted to overwrite, please use this below command.

```
$ kubectl label node worker1  node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker --overwrite
```

Comment: You can choose your node to have any role like `node-role.kubernetes.io/testing=testing-worker` and `node-role.kubernetes.io/system=system-worker`... The column ROLES will display the value(s) separated by comma in case multiple values exist

Answer (score 2):

In my case i was able to do that with below commands

```
kubectl label nodes ip-10-0-47-13.ec2.internal kubernetes.io/role=worker
```

**Output**

```
node/ip-10-0-47-13.ec2.internal labeled

mansoor.hasan@PURE-DEV-MANSOORHASAN EKS % kubectl get nodes                                                       
NAME                         STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
ip-10-0-47-13.ec2.internal   Ready    worker   161m   v1.20.15-eks-fb459a0
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of everything that has already been answered since k8S 1.16, [the kubernetes.io/ and k8s.io/ prefixes are reserved for Kubernetes core components.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#syntax-and-character-set)

The suggested way is to create your own namespace to label a kubernetes node by simply reproducing the kubelet way.

For example as a label key `node-role.[your-domain]/[role]=`. No label value is needed, the label key is actually a tag.

```
kubectl label node [node-name] node-role.[your-namespace]/[role]=
```

Where:

- `node-name` is your node name (returned by `kubectl get node`)
- `your-namespace` is the "domain" of your namespace (eg. acme.org)
- `role` is the node role, (eg. `database`)

For example:

```
kubectl label node node001 node-role.acme.org/database=
```