# Kubernetes join node preflight pending after docker version warning

Tags: kubernetes

I'm Doing some homework ( linuxacademy tutorial ) with kubernetes ( 1 masters and 2 nodes )
Trying add my node1 using command kubeadm join on the node.

The command is pending without any error or result.
I have tried on the node2 and I have the exact same result.
I must kill the process with ctrl+c to exit

```
[root@K8SNode2 rbo]# kubeadm join 192.168.1.43:6443 --token 9jh998.01jsgbnvsg9373ix \
>     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:60df8024a4ee96018136424af429c5c16ffd15805                                                                                                                53128c83d4fc4861829197f
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING SystemVerification]: this Docker version is not on the list of valid                                                                                                                ated versions: 19.03.1. Latest validated version: 18.09
```

running on CentOs7 minimal, installation on master seems good

```
[rbo@K8SMaster ~]$ kubectl get nodes
NAME        STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
k8smaster   Ready    master   8h    v1.15.3
```

Thaks for help

Comment: Please share `docker version` output of master and compute/worker nodes

Comment: @prometherion Master: 'Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89'
Nodes: Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89'

Comment: Are you sure the node can communicate with the master? Please try `nc -zv 192.168.1.43 6443`

Comment: @prometherion : ( I have installed nc ) nc -zv 192.168.1.43 6443
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: No route to host.
But Ping is working fine

Comment: @prometherion Thanks for guided me on the root cause, I have opened the port with firewall command on both side and it's seem's working fine.

Comment: @prometherion: NAME        STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
k8smaster   Ready    master   17h   v1.15.3
k8snode1    Ready    <none>   95s   v1.15.3
The none status for the node is normal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, we found the issue wasn't related to unsupported Docker version but to missing Firewalld open port `6443` on *Master* node: you can solve it using the simple command `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=6443/tcp` along with a `firewall-cmd --reload`.

After that, the node joined as expected but `<none>` role is attached and that's [expected](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55232#issuecomment-342471004): you have to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48856238/10104472) in order to mark the node as *worker* using the key-value label `node.kubernetes.io/role=worker`

Comment: @rab since you're new to SO, please give me a vote up :)

Comment: @promotherion I'am sorry under 15 of réputation I cannot vote.

Comment: @promotherion But when I got them I'll bé black for vote 