# How to remove a label from a kubernetes object just with "kubectl apply -f file.yaml"?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, label, openshift, argocd

I'm playing around with GitOps and ArgoCD in Redhat Openshift. My goal is to switch a worker node to an infra node.

I want to do this with descriptive YAML Files, and NOT manually by using the command line (that's easy with kubectl label node ...)

In order to do make the node an infra node, I want to add a label "infra" and take the label "worker" from it. Before, the object looks like this (irrelevant labels omitted):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Node
metadata:
  labels:
    node-role.kubernetes.io/infra: ""
  name: node6.example.com
spec: {}
```

After applying a YAML File, it's supposed to look like that:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Node
metadata:
  labels:
    node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: ""
  name: node6.example.com
spec: {}
```

If I put the latter config in a file, and do "kubectl apply -f ", the node has both infra and worker labels. So adding a label or changing the value of a label is easy, but is there a way to remove a label in an objects metadata by applying a YAML file ?

Comment: I don't think it is good idea to change the label on node instead of creating new MachineSets for infrastructure node.

Answer (score 1):

you can delete the label with

```
kubectl label node node6.example.com node-role.kubernetes.io/infra-
```

than you can run the `kubectl apply` again with the new label.
You will be up and running.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's not possible to do with `kubectl apply`, at least I tried and couldn't find any informations about that.

As @Petr Kotas mentioned you can always use

```
kubectl label node node6.example.com node-role.kubernetes.io/infra-
```

But I see you're looking for something else

> I want to do this with descriptive YAML Files, and NOT manually by using the command line (that's easy with kubectl label node ...)

---

So maybe the answer could be to use API clients, for example [python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python)? I have found this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54168783/11977760), made by @Prafull Ladha

> As already mentioned, correct kubectl example to delete label, but there is no mention of removing labels using API clients. if you want to remove label using the API, then you need to provide a new body with the `labelname: None` and then patch that body to the node or pod. I am using the kubernetes python client API for example purpose

```
from pprint import pprint
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()
client.configuration.debug = True

api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()

body = {
    "metadata": {
        "labels": {
            "label-name": None}
        }
}

api_response = api_instance.patch_node("minikube", body)

print(api_response)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've pretty successfully changed a node label in my Kubernetes cluster (created using kubeadm) using `kubectl replace` and `kubectl apply`.

**Required:** If your node configuration was changed manually using imperative command like `kubectl label` it's required to fix `last-applied-configuration` annotation using the following command *(replace node2 with your node name)*:

```
kubectl get node node2 -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

**Note:** It works in the same way with **all types** of Kubernetes objects (with slightly different consequences. Always check the results).

**Note2**: `--export` argument for `kubectl get` is deprecated, and it works well without it, but if you use it the `last-applied-configuration` annotation appears to be much shorter and easier to read.

Without applying existing configuration, the next `kubectl apply` command will ignore all fields that are not present in the `last-applied-configuration` annotation.
The following example illustrate that [behavior](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/#how-apply-calculates-differences-and-merges-changes):

```
kubectl get node node2 -o yaml | grep node-role 

  {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Node","metadata":{"annotations":{"flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-data":"{\"VtepMAC\":\"46:c6:d1:f0:6c:0a\"}","flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-type":"vxlan","flannel.alpha.coreos.com/kube-subnet-manager":"true","flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip":"10.156.0.11","kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket":"/var/run/dockershim.sock","node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl":"0","volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach":"true"},"creationTimestamp":null,  
"labels":{  
 "beta.kubernetes.io/arch":"amd64", 
 "beta.kubernetes.io/os":"linux",
 "kubernetes.io/arch":"amd64",
 "kubernetes.io/hostname":"node2",
 "kubernetes.io/os":"linux",
 "node-role.kubernetes.io/worker":""},          # <--- important line: only worker label is present
 "name":"node2","selfLink":"/api/v1/nodes/node2"},"spec":{"podCIDR":"10.244.2.0/24"},"status":{"daemonEndpoints":{"kubeletEndpoint":{"Port":0}},"nodeInfo":{"architecture":"","bootID":"","containerRuntimeVersion":"","kernelVersion":"","kubeProxyVersion":"","kubeletVersion":"","machineID":"","operatingSystem":"","osImage":"","systemUUID":""}}}
node-role.kubernetes.io/santa: ""
node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: ""
```

Let's check what happened with `node-role.kubernetes.io/santa` label if I try to replace the *worker* with *infra* and remove *santa*, ( *worker* is present in the annotation):

```
# kubectl diff is used to comare the current online configuration, and the configuration as it would be if applied
kubectl get node node2 -o yaml | sed 's@node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: ""@node-role.kubernetes.io/infra: ""@' | sed 's@node-role.kubernetes.io/santa: ""@@'| kubectl diff -f -

diff -u -N /tmp/LIVE-380689040/v1.Node..node2 /tmp/MERGED-682760879/v1.Node..node2
--- /tmp/LIVE-380689040/v1.Node..node2   2020-04-08 17:20:18.108809972 +0000
+++ /tmp/MERGED-682760879/v1.Node..node2 2020-04-08 17:20:18.120809972 +0000
@@ -18,8 +18,8 @@
     kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
     kubernetes.io/hostname: node2
     kubernetes.io/os: linux
+    node-role.kubernetes.io/infra: ""         # <-- created as desired
     node-role.kubernetes.io/santa: ""         # <-- ignored, because the label isn't present in the last-applied-configuration annotation
-    node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: ""        # <-- removed as desired
   name: node2
   resourceVersion: "60973814"
   selfLink: /api/v1/nodes/node2
exit status 1
```

After fixing annotation  (by running `kubectl get node node2 -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -` ), `kubectl apply` works pretty well replacing and removing labels:

```
kubectl get node node2 -o yaml | sed 's@node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: ""@node-role.kubernetes.io/infra: ""@' | sed 's@node-role.kubernetes.io/santa: ""@@'| kubectl diff -f -

diff -u -N /tmp/LIVE-107488917/v1.Node..node2 /tmp/MERGED-924858096/v1.Node..node2
--- /tmp/LIVE-107488917/v1.Node..node2   2020-04-08 18:01:55.776699954 +0000
+++ /tmp/MERGED-924858096/v1.Node..node2 2020-04-08 18:01:55.792699954 +0000
@@ -18,8 +18,7 @@
     kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
     kubernetes.io/hostname: node2
     kubernetes.io/os: linux
-    node-role.kubernetes.io/santa: ""         # <-- removed as desired
-    node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: ""        # <-- removed as desired, literally replaced with the following label
+    node-role.kubernetes.io/infra: ""         # <-- created as desired
   name: node2
   resourceVersion: "60978298"
   selfLink: /api/v1/nodes/node2
exit status 1
```

Here are a few more examples:

```
# Check the original label ( last filter removes last applied config annotation line)
$ kubectl get node node2 -o yaml | grep node-role | grep -v apiVersion
    node-role.kubernetes.io/infra: ""

# Replace the label "infra" with "worker" using kubectl replace syntax
$ kubectl get node node2 -o yaml | sed 's@node-role.kubernetes.io/infra: ""@node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: ""@' | kubectl replace -f -
node/node2 replaced

# check the new state of the label
$ kubectl get node node2 -o yaml | grep node-role | grep -v apiVersion
    node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: ""
# label replaced     -------^^^^^^

# Replace the label "worker" back to "infra" using kubectl apply syntax
$ kubectl get node node2 -o yaml | sed 's@node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: ""@node-role.kubernetes.io/infra: ""@' | kubectl apply -f -
node/node2 configured

# check the new state of the label
$ kubectl get node node2 -o yaml | grep node-role | grep -v apiVersion
    node-role.kubernetes.io/infra: ""  
# label replaced     -------^^^^^

# Remove the label from the node ( for demonstration purpose)
$ kubectl get node node2 -o yaml | sed 's@node-role.kubernetes.io/infra: ""@@' | kubectl apply -f -
node/node2 configured

# check the new state of the label
$ kubectl get node node2 -o yaml | grep node-role | grep -v apiVersion
# empty output
# label "infra" has been removed
```

You may see the following warning when you use `kubectl apply -f` on the  resource created using imperative commands like `kubectl create` or `kubectl expose` for the first time:

```
Warning: kubectl apply should be used on resource created by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply
```

In this case `last-applied-configuration` annotation will be created with the content of the file used in `kubectl apply -f filename.yaml` command. It may not contain all parameters and labels that are present in the live object.

Comment: For the openshift cluster it should work in the same way, either with `kubectl` or `oc` 
 https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/cli_reference/differences_oc_kubectl.html

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the worker label to false:

```
node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: "false"
```

Worked for me on OpenShift 4.4.

**Edit:**
This doesn't work. What happened was:

- Applied YML file containing node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: "false"
- Automated process ran deleting the node-role.kubernetes.io/worker label from the node (due to it not being specified in the YML it would automatically apply)

What's funny is that the automated process would not delete the label if it was empty instead of set to false.